# I'd like to know how to convert variable value to number in ASCII array?

Tags: c, ascii

I'd like to know how to convert variable value to number in ASCII array?
For example:

```
int a=8;
```

I can check that '8' is 56 but how to write in a code?

```
      int  a=8;
      b=(char)('(char)(a)');
      printf(" %d",b);
```

I came up with that but I don't know if it's right.

Comment: Add `'0'`. Like `8 + '0'`

Answer (score -1):

Assign the character constant `'8'` to `a` and print that.

```
int a = '8';
printf("%d\n", a);
```

If you're working with the value 8, you can use the fact that the character constants `'0'` to `'9'` are guaranteed to be sequential and add the value of the character constant `'0'` to the value you have:

```
int a = 8;
printf("%d\n", a + '0');
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have to write a=8 because I use that in previous part of the code and  what I have to do if I only know that a=8?

Comment: @Tommy0930 See my edit.  Add the value of `'0'`

Comment: Okey. Now, I understand :)

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to convert anything. If you have an array holding the values, print the array

- using `%c` to print the character representation (digit)
- using  `%d` to print the decimal value in ASCII.

Sample code:

```
#include  <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int arr [10] = {0};
    
    // initialize array
    for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++) {arr[i] = '0' + i;}
    
    //print values
    for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++) {
        printf ("Element %d: Character value = %c, Decimal value =%d\n", (i+1), arr[i], arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```